Is there global search in the Visual Studio Code? (files and content at the same time)
At the PyCharm it's a double shift. Is there any global search in the VS Code so I can search by file names and it's content at the same time?
I'm using ubuntu 22.04 if this is matters.
Version: 1.89.1
Commit: dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685
Date: 2024-05-07T05:16:23.416Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.0-28-generic


related on SU: https://superuser.com/q/1493167/1749748

answer deleted. as question poster is not interested.

Not that I know of.
For file names, there's Quick Open and the find widget in the Explorer View, and for file contents, there's the Search View, Search Editors, and more recently, Quick Search.
If you really want this, you can raise a feature-request issue ticket.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
